# write to a folder and the security risks

Tags: php, permissions

I'm using a `Thumbnail` plugin. It store thumbs in a folder on webroot. 
but when it's trying to save the thumb, returns "no writable" error. it directory permission is `755`.
If i change permission to `777`, error disappears. but I read somewhere `777` permission can cause security issues..

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could change the owner (e.g. `chown www-data:www-data your/direcotry/path` in linux)

```
chown [OPTIONS] [Owner][:[Group]] FilenameOrFoldername
```

that the web-server user (the user who executes php scripts) owns the directory, then he has write access and you can leave the rights to 755.

7 5 5 = rwx r-x r-x

**r**ead **w**rite e**x**ecute

first digit = owner
second digit = group
third digit = all other users

means that only the owner has write access (he can add files to the directory in this case the www-data user), the group (www-data) has read and execute rights and the rest has read and execute rights too, so there should not be a security risc with 755.

[Here](http://www.onlineconversion.com/html_chmod_calculator.htm) you have a tool where you can calculate the right -> chmod number conversion

Comment: This seems like the right solution, give the correct permissions to just the user that needs it.

Answer (score 0):

the rights is written as owner/group/other, i think you can use 775 rights for your logic.

Answer (score 0):

You could store it somewhere that the web server (like apache or nginx) can't access but your web app server (php, java servlet, whatever) can, and make logic for it to grab it from that folder and serve it up as an image.  That way, you ensure that any files uploaded by users aren't ever executed.

It would cost more server resources, so that's something you should consider.

If the files are created by your app and there is no way for the user to directly modify them, then there is no problem with giving it write permissions.

Comment: bad solution. too much processing for core. but if it doesnt matter, so its the best.

Comment: for user's files it's the best, but in my app, users never upload a file. app creates an image and a thumb, store it somewhere, and shows to users